# Chrome for Android's cache location

Tags: chrome-for-android, cache

I am using a Samsung Note 2 (N7100) running on root. I want to know where Chrome for Android saves its cache files.

Like on Windows, the cache is located on `..\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1\Cache`.

Where is the location for Chrome for Android's cache?

Answer (score 1):

Like other Android apps, Chrome for Android stores the cache under its data directory which is `/data/data/com.android.chrome/cache`. `Cache` and `Media Cache` goes there.

`GPUCache` is located under `/data/data/com.android.chrome/app_chrome/Default/`.

Related reading on [Forensic Wiki](http://forensicswiki.org/wiki/Google_Chrome).

Comment: If think you wanted to say "/android/data/com.android.." instead of "/data/data/com.android..."

Comment: @ZéCarlos back when I posted the answer I meant what I wrote, but I do not know whether my answer is applicable to recent versions of Android now.

Comment: It's valid for Android 11