# Gmail app cache on Android

Tags: email, gmail, cache

A while ago, I received an email with an image in the message body. It was attached via URL source. I have read that message on my Android device and saw the image there as well. When I go to the mail now, the image no longer loads - it has been taken down, the URL doesn't work anymore. I need to gain access to that image.

I imagine the Gmail app stores data (even temporarily) somewhere on the device, so I'm looking for a way to extract that image. Here's what I've found so far.

I'm browsing my phone internal memory via my laptop. I have *show hidden files* option enabled.

`Android/data/com.google.android.gm/files` is empty.

`Android/data/com.google.android.gm/cache` has several files like these:

```
1e4d24dc66d8c27bcfe49ac8c74d285d    2107KB
2b04c4c91cdd6f9507d3b40dca0fce31    10522KB
2fb23268fce84c1fb85382eb0d5fbc7e    10410KB
...
```

I'm pretty sure the answer lies somewhere in these files. Anyone know a way to extract data from them?

Comment: App data can't be accessed without root https://android.stackexchange.com/q/47924/131553

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where Android apps store data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47924/where-android-apps-store-data)

Comment: Also see this https://android.stackexchange.com/q/46926/131553

Comment: @beeshyams I've read through these threads and what I'm getting from them is that the data stored under `/data/data` isn't accessible from `adb` or a PC, without root. Ok, I get that. What about these files I do have access for? Is there a way to extract anything useful from them?

Comment: No idea what those files are or how to open them (cookies?)// 1. [Cache is also stored in `/data/data`](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/122847/131553) and hence requires root// 2. [Connecting to PC through USB (MTP) doesn't expose underlying filesystem (`ext4` or `f2fs`) of internal storage (`/data` partition) to PC](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205559/131553)// IMO your question is a dupe of [1]//  No root, no luck

Comment: Sorry for my confusion here. I linked Chrome related answers above but it's [applicable to Gmail too](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/27187/131553)

Comment: @beeshyams that's no problem, I get the idea. Though I would like to find out what these files on /Android/data are for and if they can be useful in any way.

Comment: You could ask a separate question on that linking this as background